# Ansible Playbook syntax check issue

Tags: centos, ansible

i have below detail in /etc/ansible/hosts

```
[dev] 10.13.212.32
```

and i am able ping this hosts as below:

```
# ansible dev -m ping
```

Output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ansible dev -m ping
10.13.212.32 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
```

when i check syntax of  *.yml file .

```
# ansible-playbook --syntax-check --list-tasks -i hosts ./nginx.yml
```

or

```
# ansible-playbook nginx.yml --check**
 [WARNING]: Unable to parse /root/hosts as an inventory source

 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected '-' indicator
```

The error appears to have been in '/root/nginx.yml': line 3, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
- name: install and start nginx
hosts: localhost
^ here
```

help me out with the issue.

Comment: can u check the host declaration?

Answer (score 0):

The error is exactly what is says, there is no `/root/hosts` file!

```
ansible-playbook --syntax-check --list-tasks -i hosts ./nginx.yml
```

With the `-i` switch (`--inventory-file`), you are pointing to the file `/root/hosts` (since you are running as `root`, from `root`'s `$HOME`) instead of the file:

```
/etc/ansible/hosts
```

So, try again with:

```
ansible-playbook --syntax-check --list-tasks -i /etc/ansible/hosts ./nginx.yml
```

And your playbook fails due to incorrect syntax and indentation. Check [this example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-language-example) for starters.